# Regular Expression for 15 digit number and max 2 decimal places

Tags: regex

Heu guys, so i'm trying to validate a amount field in witch i want the left part to be max 15 digits plus it can have up to 2 decimal places.

So i'm in this site trying out the validation https://regex101.com/
And this regex works as expected in this site:

```
^\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[image]

When i test it in the code it does not accept the decimal places

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me understand what is happening?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is likely you can only use regex validation on string types. Here, you can just use a custom validation method.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are correct, changed the Amout field to string and tested it, and works as expected. Maybe i will have to develope a custom validation for double fields :\

Comment: Or, maybe it just did not like the nullable type? At any rate, a custom method would still be preferable here, I believe.